# Resharper CLI Cleanup is removing C# explicit parameter names

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

I have this line under [*.cs] in my editorconfig:

`resharper_redundant_explicit_positional_property_declaration_highlighting = none`

But when I run `dotnet jb cleanupcode MySolution.sln`, named parameters are still removed.  These are important e.g. in a long param list where we want to verify in code review that we are not passing e.g. Name for Phone or vice versa.

Any clue on why this would still be happening?  Resharper CLI is respecting the rest of my .editorconfig file, e.g. line length and indent size when I change those.

I can work around this by scrambling the order of parameters so the CLI doesn't think they're redundant, but that seems pretty hacky.

Alternatively, maybe there's a way to enforce named parameters when declaring a record (similar to constructing a JS interface), but I haven't found it.

Sample code before running cleanup:

```cs
    var account = new Account(
        Name: app.Applicant.CompanyName,
        BillingStreet: app.Applicant.MailingAddress1,
        Address_Unit: app.Applicant.MailingAddress2);
```

And after:

```cs
    var account = new Account(
        app.Applicant.CompanyName,
        app.Applicant.MailingAddress1,
        app.Applicant.MailingAddress2);
```

Comment: I think you may want to create a cleanup profile in the dialog with "Apply Arguments Style (named vs positional)" unticked, save it, and use that profile?

Comment: @whybird I would definitely like to but am just using the CLI, not Resharper.  I guess I could try using the free demo for that.  So far after some investigation the best solution I have is to use the most basic Formatting profile, which of course loses some features: `→ dotnet jb cleanupcode --profile="Built-in: Reformat Code" --exclude="**/*.js" ../../MySolution.sln`

Comment: I'm curious what happens if you call `dotnet jb cleanupcode --no-buildin-settings MySolution.sln` ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CleanupCode.html#parameters-for-resharper-settings)). Does this affect your output anyway? But I'm pretty sure that whybird is right and you have to create a custom cleanup profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to create a custom Profile for Resharper clean-up.

1. Download Rider
2. Create a copy of the Full clean profile
3. Disable the option: 'Apply Arguments Style (named vs positional)'
4. Export the profile
5. Use the profile when running cleanup

(Thanks to @whybird for providing the relevant comment)